# Suffix -ed indicating current state

Tags: syntax, english, morphology, tense

I'm noticing that some English verbs use the -ed suffix to indicate the current state. Using this example: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/base

Specifically, the verb sense, ‘the film is **based** on a novel by Pat Conroy’

I (incorrectly?) thought current state verbs were presented in base form or progressive form. Are there a set of verbs that use -ed to indicate current state? Is there a name for this concept?

Comment: is + past participle = passive

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [elu.se]

Answer (score 6):

"Based" here is either the past/passive participle of the verb *base* used in the [passive](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922) construction "BE + past participle", or an adjective derived from the past participle (a *departicipial adjective*—also known as a "participial adjective").  "The film is based on a novel by Pat Conroy" means approximately the  same thing as "[The creators of the film] based the film on a novel by Pat Conroy".

Running through a few tests for establishing adjective-hood, I couldn't find a totally clear indication of whether "based" is an adjective or a participle in this context<sup>1</sup>.

But in either case, it's not really a case of using *-ed* to mark a verb form indicating the current state. The thing that indicates present state in this sentence is mainly the auxiliary "is".

### Tests for adjective-hood in English

1. I go over some of these tests in my answer to a [question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/366940/77227) (which is partly based on BillJ's answer on the same page).

#### "very" test

In my judgement, "based" in this sentence doesn't pass the "very" test.
The "very" test for distinguishing departicipial adjectives from participles is based on the commonly accepted fact that a verb cannot be modified by the word "very" (in a comment below, Greg Lee gave the following example showing how we can see that "very" obviously doesn't work with "based" when it is used as a finite verb: "*The author very based the film on a novel"). Therefore, if the word "based" in your sentence can be modified by the word "very", we can be sure that it is not a verb (and so we would assume that it is a departicipial adjective). But in fact, we can't modify "based" with "very" in your sentence:

- *"the film is very based on a novel by Pat Conroy"

Not all adjectives can be modified by "very", so failing the "very" test doesn't prove that something isn't an adjective. Thus, the "very" test is inconclusive.

#### "un-" test

"Based" in this context also doesn't seem to past the "un-" test, which establishes that something is an adjective (keeping in mind that the adjective prefix "un-"  functions as a negative prefix, unlike the "reversative" verb prefix "un-"):

- *"the film is unbased on a novel by Pat Conroy"

As with the "very" test, this only fails to show that "based" is an adjective here: it doesn't show that "based" is not an adjective, because not all adjectives can be prefixed with *un-.* (In fact, based on the results of a Google search, the word *based* followed by a prepositional phrase starting in *on* can be prefixed with *un-* in some other sentences, so it seems that *based* is an adjective sometimes; but I'm not sure what the criteria are for when it is and isn't possible to use "unbased on..."--it may be that only some speakers use this construction.)

#### "seems" test

"Based" in "based on a novel by Pat Conroy" might be able to pass the "seem" test, which is apparently considered to establish that something is not a verb/participle:

- ?"the film seems based on a novel by Pat Conroy"

Compare the use of the in my view semantically similar "seems based on a true story" in the following quote:

- > Sometimes it really seems based on a true story...

  ("[‘Masterminds’ should go straight to the Brew and View](https://medium.com/@matt_pais/masterminds-should-go-straight-to-the-brew-and-view-2f05e8379070)", Matt Pais, Sep 29, 2016, medium.com)

#### Summary

One test out of three doesn't seem quite convincing to me; also, even if it is the case that "based" is an adjective in some sentences, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is an adjective in the original sentence that you brought up. That said, it's true that the sentence has a stative rather than a dynamic meaning, and "stative" passives often are analyzed as containing departicipial adjectives rather than participles.

One interesting thing about *based on...* (or *unbased on...*) as an adjective is that the prepositional phrase starting with "on" seems to be an obligatory complement. According to Rodney Huddleston's *[Introduction to the Grammar of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=irXAKZSHc38C&pg=PA305&lpg=PA305&dq=english%20adjective%20with%20obligatory%20complement&source=bl&ots=7xHbhimNmB&sig=JaaQwrd_ZrfwD4jBhqHSJmO6xzM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2jfmQ7pjaAhVKyoMKHeKKAaw4ChDoAQhTMAY#v=onepage&q=english%20adjective%20with%20obligatory%20complement&f=false),* "very few adjectives take obligatory complements" (p. 305)--Huddleston gives the example *fond*: we can say "Sally is fond of sweets" but not *"Sally is fond". Other examples are *devoid of* and *lo(a)th to.*

Comment: It seems to fail both ways in *"the based film was too long" and *"the film was based by an agent"

Comment: @amI: I don't think those examples actually tell use much about the part of speech of "based". It might just be the case that "based" is an adjective that cannot be used without a complement PP starting with "on", in the same way that we don't usually use the verb "base" without a complement PP.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it a phrasal verb -- another point for 'participle'?

Comment: @amI: I think adjectives can take mandatory PP complements. I'm finding it hard to think of an example like "based", but for example it seems like in "familar [with X]", the PP "with X" is a mandatory PP complement. [The word "familar" can be used as an adjective without a PP complement, but not without a change in meaning.](https://gawron.sdsu.edu/syntax/course_core/lectures/comp_adj.htm) Other similar examples might be *authorized to* and *permitted to.*

Comment: @amI: Other examples of adjectives that obligatorily take complements that I think I have found from the results of myGoogle searches about this topic: *devoid of, lo(a)th to.*

Comment: ... but 'phrasal adjective' means something else.  Is there a name for phrases like 'familiar with'?

Comment: @amI: I don't know of any simpler term than "an adjective that takes an obligatory PP complement" but I'm just constructing that out of other grammar terms that I know. I've just started to research this and I haven't found any short term yet; let me know if you learn of one!

Comment: The thing that makes "very ___" a good test for whether an -ed word is a passive participle is the fact that "very" doesn't modify verbs:  "*The author very based the film on a novel." Passivization doesn't convert a verb into an adjective -- it's still a verb.  It's not whether the adjective is "gradable" or the verb complement is appropriate.

Comment: @GregLee: I don't think "very" can be used with all adjectives, and I think the adjectives that it can't be used with tend to be ungradable. For example, I believe that *former* is classified as an adjective, but we can't say *very former;* we also can't say *more former* or *the most former.* I found another example, *very monetary,* given in a book that seems to say the reason *very* can't be used before these adjectives is because they are used with a classifying function: https://books.google.com/books?id=eUSxewP4KqgC&pg=PA57&dq=%22very+for#v=onepage&q=%22very%20for&f=false

Comment: @sumelic, Did I somehow imply that "very" can be used with all adjectives? "based" isn't an adjective, so what's the relevance?

Comment: @GregLee: I don't understand how you know that "based" isn't an adjective. Could you explain the argument for that in more detail? Passivization by itself doesn't convert a verb into an adjective, but departicipial adjectives clearly exist.

Comment: @sumelic, Well, if there is no adjective "based", that is a sufficient explanation for the unacceptability of *"very based".  If that were due to the hypothetical adjective "based" not being gradable, why is "partially based" perfectly okay? (Answer: it's because, unlike "very", "partially" does modify verbs.)  //  I don't believe there is such a thing as a "departicipialized" adjective, though of course there are some adjectives derived from verbs by adding -ed.  But, unlike inflections, particular derivational forms need not always exist.  A film based on something is not a "based film".

Comment: @GregLee: Thanks for the example with "partially". I have removed all references to gradability from my post; I might ask a separate question after I do I bit more thinking and reading.

Comment: @GregLee: Different authors call the same adjectives "participial adjectives", "departicipial adjectives", "deverbal adjectives", but I didn't think this difference in terminology signified anything important. [Huddleston](https://books.google.com/books?id=R4gl7uo7QTMC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=%22departicipial+adjective%22&source=bl&ots=lsr8s76LY8&sig=nCDogQcMjr) defines a *departicipial adjective* as "an adjective derived (by conversion) from the participial form of a verb."

Comment: @GregLee: I'm not sure I understand your point of view about the way these adjectives are derived, and how it conflicts with the term "departicipial adjective" as defined above by Huddleston. Would you say that an adjective like "broken" should not be analyzed as being derived from the past-participle form "broken" of the verb *broke,* but instead as being derived from the verb *broke* + a suffix *-en*?

Comment: @sumelic, No, I don't know about "broken".  Do you predict the acceptability of "He was very broken on the wheel."? I'm not sure it is even possible to derive words from inflected forms.

Comment: @GregLee: I wouldn't predict that. I agree with what you said about particular derivational forms not needing to exist. "Broken" does seem to exist as an adjective in some contexts, like the following sentence: "[He was very broken from what the world had thrown at him](https://books.google.com/books?id=2DK_DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT63&dq=%22very+broken+from%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu28vqg5DaAhWFxIMKHQsIDY)." As for deriving words from inflected forms: what about "menswear"? Isn't that a word where the "mens" part is derived from the genitive plural inflected form of *man*? Or do compounds not count?

Comment: @sumelic, "mens wear" is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

The state is an acquired state meaning that it does not necessarily follow from the semantics of the word "film": *Film*, in its "naked" sense, does not have to be "based" to mean *film*. In adding the participle "based", the speaker refers to (albeit with inferior focus on) the external force that caused the change of state of the film (i. e. the force that made *a* film *that* film). The film, as an enduring, "reverberating" manifestation (canonically irreversible manifestation that is) of that input of effort, is a result, usually explicated using a perfect form to become understood as a result of that input. Passive and perfect often go hand in hand, since the latter is learned by thinking through the former: "I cut the apple." (active) > "(Now see,) The apple is cut." (result, perfect) > "The apple is *being*/*becomes* cut." (passive)
Without supposing a perfect (=(canonically irreversible) result) state (such as the apple by itself staying irreversibly cut) one would never grasp the gradient of force, one could never distinguish between subject and object.
In short: present-imperfective-active; past-perfective-passive. Present passive is a complex of those more primitive aspect/tenses. The passive follows from the perfect.
The ambiguity comes from "is based" being both interpretable as perfect (i. e. result *after* conclusion of action) or as passive (i. e. result co-occuring with action (of *being affected*)), as sumelic has already pointed out in the first paragraph of her/his answer.

Cf. Uni Konstanz' Universals #507, #895, #958 (https://typo.uni-konstanz.de/archive/nav/browse.php?number=1&PHPSESSID=udvvebsagjco5gls4m5sm8aj451ca7nc)